# Android emulator throws error: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Tags: android

I am new to Android development. I have installed Android studio on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 32 bit version. 
When the emulator is run from command line, it throws 'Exec format error'. Having faced similar issues with 'adb' it seems to be an incompatible executable of Android 'emulator'.

Kindly let me know where to find a 32-bit executable of android emulator.

I have searched quite a bit on Google and didn't find.

Comment: The fix was to downloaded an older version of android sdk, http://dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz, and copied Sdk/tools folder from the older version to the Android SDK installation path. And, launch emulator from command line with -force-32bit option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

downloaded an older version of android sdk, dl.google.com/android/android-sdk_r24.4.1-linux.tgz, and copied Sdk/tools folder from the older version to the Android SDK installation path. And, launch emulator from command line with -force-32bit option. With this i am able to use the emulator to run apps.